# What are supervised ML Classification algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

What I found are:
1. Naive Bayes classifier
2. K nearest neighbors classifier
3. Decision tree Algorithms(C4.5, Random Forest)
4. Kernel Discriminant Analysis
5. Support vector machines

If any other, can someone please help me with the remaining algorithms under this? I need complete list of supervised ML classification algorithms for my academic purpose. Thank you

Comment: The type of question of "Please list all X" is a bad fit for StackOverflow. Also, this list is incomplete as new algorithms are invented every day. (Voting to close).

Comment: please do tell me any source where can I get.After searching in Google only, I asked this question. where can I ask this type of questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is an active area of research, I wouldn't say new algorithms are invented every day, not good ones anyway. The invention of a new ML algorithm that is better than the rest in even some semi-important particular cases would be pretty big news.

Usually, known algorithms are adapted to a given problem. Adapting one properly can itself be an area of research (spam classification is done with classical ML algorithms, but it's not trivial to perfect, so is digit recognition etc.)

Regardless, it's hard to find a source that lists all the known, classical algorithms. There are a lot, and it's unlikely that an author somewhere lists them all. They usually list the ones they work with, or the ones they consider the most important.

That said, I'm going to try to give you a longer list, and I'm making this community wiki to encourage other people to add more.

1. Naive Bayes classifier
2. K nearest neighbors classifier
3. Decision tree Algorithms(C4.5, Random Forest)
4. Kernel Discriminant Analysis
5. Support vector machines
6. Logistic Regression
7. Passive Aggressive Classifiers
8. Gaussian Processes
9. Neural networks
10. The Winnow algorithm

Comment: @IVIad  Thank you so much for your encouragement and positive reply.